# How to read an XML using Xmlreader in java?

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xmlreader

I have an XML file and want to read the information using XPath, I want to read the 'listings_Id' and 'budget_remaining' together.

XML example

```
<ads>
 <ad>
   <listing_ids>
     <listing_id>2235</listing_id>
     <listing_id>303</listing_id>
     <listing_id>394</listing_id>
  </listing_ids>
  <reference_id>11</reference_id>
  <net_ppe>0.55</net_ppe>
  <budget_remaining>50000.0</budget_remaining>
</ad>
<ad>
   <listing_ids>
     <listing_id>2896</listing_id>
   </listing_ids>
   <reference_id>8</reference_id>
   <net_ppe>1.5</net_ppe>
   <budget_remaining>1.3933399</budget_remaining>
 </ad>
</ads>
```

I want to output it to a CSV file as the following

```
ListingId,BudgetRemaining
2235,0.55
303,0.55
394,0.5
2896,1.5
```

I am trying to use the example as

```
  DataReader reader = new XmlReader(new File("links.xml"))
    .addField("ListingId", "//ad/listing_ids/listing_id")
    .addField("BudgetRemaining", "//ad/budget_remaining")
    .addRecordBreak("//ad")
    .setExpandDuplicateFields(true);
```

But it seems so I cannot find the jar file for XMLReader and DataReader and also I am going definitely wrong with the format. New to Java, please any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure what tutorial you followed / where you copied that code from, but that's not the default Java XPath implementation you're trying to use. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811001/how-to-read-xml-using-xpath-in-java?rq=1.

Comment: @JensErat : I followed the same example, it is an Xmlreader, but I cannot find the jar file for it.

Comment: Just realized, it's the third answer. The library is linked just above the code! Anyway, if there's no special reason (the possibility of directly outputting CSV might be one, I don't know that library) you might consider going for the first answer and just use the "standard Java way" of doing the stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You're following a tutorial for a commercial library (["Data Pipeline"](http://northconcepts.com/data-pipeline/)), which is not shipped with the JDK and needs to be installed separately. Get if [from the Download page](http://northconcepts.com/downloads/) and install it using their [Getting Started](http://northconcepts.com/data-pipeline/getting-started/) manual.

Now, the classes should be found.